# Scrape NFT's item's price

Tags: web-scraping, nft, opensea

I'm looking to obtain individual item information for each NFT transaction, including historical prices and related details, in order to predict the price of NFTs.

I'm aware that API can provide the floor price for each collection, but those API not focus on item-level information for each transaction. Most API only could scrape bottom price.

How to get the historical price? Could I directly scrape from website?

I have tried some API from opensea. I find those are bottom prices for a whole collection.